# Meaning of a phrase, with focus on the word “titine”

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire, argot

What do the following mean?

> mais je ne pourrai pas t'offrir ma titine.
>   Je veux elle ne pourra pas t'offrir sa titine.

Comment: I suggest you clarify in which context you have found these two sentences because "titine" can have different meanings. Are you also sure about the second sentence ? It is very ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks Greg, the context is a picture (selfie) of my girlfriend sent via text message with the "titine" phrase attached.For the second sentence, the response to the photo was playfully suggesting the picture was of her girlfriend not her.

Comment: "Titine" in slang is usually an affectionate word for a car - which does not seem to make sense in the context you have described... Or it can be a nickname for first names ending with "tine" such as "Christine"... It might be just a private joke between the sender and your girlfriend ?

Comment: For the 2nd sentence, as it is a text message, I guess the sender has dropped some punctuation marks. I read it as "Je veux, elle ne pourra pas s'offrir sa titine". "Je veux" used alone is a slang phrase that means "that's for sure". But that is my reading, I expect some other contributors may read it differently. It then means "but I can't give you my *titine*. For sure, she can't give you her *titine*". What *titine* means is still a mystery, yet. Sorry to suggest that, but do you think it may have a sexual innuendo ?

Comment: Hi Greg, yeh i'm thinking it does.

Comment: The two sentences were sent by my girlfriend... referring to herself (the photo she sent of herself) and the reference to the picture being of her girlfriend.

Comment: @Joel "Titine" makes me think of "Tétine", it's the name of the small plastic toys babies suck on... I already heard people use "Titine" to refer to that. But in your context, that's quite weird, unless your gf is 2 years old.

Comment: Or licks the other side of the stamp. Answer below, but I found a forum post listing both words as occasional slang for, well, teats.

Comment: @Joel What's on the photo? Why don't you ask your girlfriend yourself?

Comment: I never heard that titine refers to à car. I think it refers to a she you have feelings for.

Answer (score 2):

People here have confused the word Titine with the word tetine.
Tetine means teat or dummy.

Here titine  probably means  car, people who really like their car usually call it titine.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It is really down to the original questioner, *je crois*, to ask his girlfriend to clear it up. The best I can offer is that it's likely something along the lines of:

> - I can't offer you my car. I want her not to offer you her car.
> - I won't be able to give you my car. I want her not to give you her car.
> - I won't give you a ride. I hope she won't give you a ride either.

Si nous acceptons «titine» as «voiture», c'est simple. **Mais @joel a indiqué dans les commentaires qu'il croit que le contexte pourrait être «insinuation sexuelle»** [or should I just say «double entendre» here?], alors ...

Certainly in English we make occasional puns on “ride” to mean both a car and sexual activity, but I'm not able to speak for whether that's currently normal in French. But, a search for "French slang" and "titine" ...

> Google says boobs.

Er, I'll rephrase.

I found [this answer](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/breasts-slang.3195278/) from [Nawaq at the `wordreference.com` forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/members/nawaq.767142/) which suggests that ***titines*** can be used to refer to, well, norks¹.

> Sein(s), poitrine (normal word), nichon(s)/nichonaille/nichonnasses, loloches (plural), boobs (the English word), eins (verlan de seins, always used in the plural), nibard(s)/nib(s), tétés (from téton "nipple"), obus (these are really big breasts), nénés, miches, roberts (not sure it's still used, really old), pare-chocs (I love this one but it's quite "offensive"), mamelles, pis (these are for cows "pis de vache", I picture a very old, not so pretty pair of breasts), airbags, titines, tétines, balcon (y a du monde au balcon, a generous pair of breasts), if you want to say something to a woman who have small breasts you can say that she's a "planche à pain" or that she has "oeufs au plat". gougoutte(e), lolos (childish), loches (I think these are big breasts "t'as vu cette grosse paire de loches ?!"), if you like fruits you can also say "ananas" and "pamplemousses" but it's not really slang I think, it's mostly old-fashioned (it comes from a song -- funny), melons, flotteurs (old-fashioned too), roploplos (old-fashioned too, sound really funny), micheton(s), signes extérieurs de richesse, boules, meules, tchoutches... there must be a ton of others but I think I'm gonna stop here.²

But again, I can't say for sure which meaning is intended.

Comment: ¹ My late father coined what I believe to be the shortest cryptic crossword clue for *knockers*, which read, *Flipping ’eck! Norks!*

Comment: ² Last phrase of the quotation from the post reminded me slightly of the Coda to Tom Lehrer’s *The Elements*.

Comment: It's quite weird to use it then in the singular. If it was some sort of sexual teasing, I would rather expect a girl to use te plural and say something like "je ne pourrai pas t'offrir mes titines/nénés/nibards/nichons". Why just ONE "boob" ?

Comment: Well, *offrir la titine* would presumably refer to breast-feeding?

Comment: The usual phrase for breast feeding is *donner le sein*, so it would rather be *donner la titine*. *Offrir* one's breast sounds weird... or sexual... *Offrir* in French is more than just *donner*, it means "giving as a present".

Comment: @joel did tell you he thought it might be in the realms of innuendo :o) [never mind, I think I misunderstood part of your explanation about the photo and responses]

Comment: About your comment on "ride": I can't think of such "sexual" metaphors in French, where riding a car hints at sex intercourse. Such double-entendre would be done with verbs such as *prendre*, *tirer* or *emballer* (sic!).

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer without context - but I have heard 'titine' be used to refer to a `dummy` (British English) or `pacifier` (American English).

It is a contracted form of

> une tétine

Comment: Thanks eveyrone. 
It seems clear what it means.
I'll close it out now.